# Ruby on rails keep executing the previous elsif statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to ruby and have a question. I am trying to implement search with two to search field. First search field will check elsif (2) and second search field will check elsif (3). When i search in first search field, if search is found, it display what i want. but when i leave the first search field empty, and enter search in second search field, it always give me the previous search result. I wrote if else statement as below:

if condition (1)

elsif condtion (2)

elsif condtion (3)

elsif condtion (4)

It seems that as long as the elsif (3) true once, it never hits the elsif condition (4).

And here is the code:

```
<h1> Search Results <h1>

<p><%= link_to 'Back', new_search_path %> </p>


<% if @search.find_users.empty? %>

<p> No Records Found </p>

<% elsif @search.find_jobs.empty? %>

<p> No Records Found1 </p>

<% elsif !@search.find_jobs.empty? %>
<% @search.find_jobs.each do |c| %>
    <%= c.title %>


    <% end %>
<% elsif !@search.find_users.empty? %>
<% @search.find_users.each do |c| %>
    <%= c.first_name %>

    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: You need a Rails tag.

Answer (score 2):

Condition 4 can never happen, because if condition 2 is false then condition 3 is automatically true, because they're exact opposites of each other.

> It seems that as long as the elsif (3) true once, it never hits the elsif condition (4).

That's just how `elsif` works - it means 'else if'. If you want 4 to show regardless of what 3 was, just end your first `if` block and start a new one.

```
<h1> Search Results <h1>
<p><%= link_to 'Back', new_search_path %> </p>

<% if @search.find_users.empty? %>
  <p> No Records Found </p>
<% else %>
  <% @search.find_users.each do |c| %>
    <%= c.first_name %>
  <% end %>
<%end%>

<% if @search.find_jobs.empty? %>
  <p> No Records Found1 </p>
<% else %>
  <% @search.find_users.each do |c| %>
    <%= c.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```